# Why did Ellis Ashmead-Barlett mention "Mediterranean leishmaniasis" to Major General Walter Braithwaite?

Tags: analysis, gallipoli

Below is a [transcript](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=237&t=17165) of a conversation in Episode 6 of [Australia's Nine Network's TV drama miniseries *Gallipoli*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallipoli_(miniseries)), that occurs at about [33:41](https://youtu.be/1QiZ9dX5cKE?t=2021), between Major General Sir Walter Braithwaite (WB) and Ellis Ashmead-Bartlett (EAB). But the transcript failed to write the names, which I had to add.

> WB — We spoke in June, Bartlett. Do you recall?
>
> EAB — Of course.
>
> WB — And do you remember the subject matter of our discussion?
>
> EAB — Hm?
>
> WB — You gave an assurance not to criticise GHQ or its officers or the conduct of the campaign.
>
> EAB — As far as I know, I've kept to this.
>
> WB  — Hmm. On September the 8th, you sent a letter, via Mr Murdoch, to Mr Asquith. An uncensored letter.
>
> EAB — Indeed I did. I have a perfect right to address my Prime Minister. How did you find out about it?
>
> WB  — That letter has been seized by us.
>
> EAB — Has it? And has it been forwarded to the proper address?
>
> WB  — I warned you I would send anyone away who spoke against the campaign.
>
> EAB — Well, then you must send away practically everyone on the peninsula, including the Turks.
>
> WB  — Your press credentials are hereby revoked. You are no longer the guest of the Army. You are to return home.
>
> EAB —  Ah. And may I leave at once?
>
> WB  —  What?
>
> EAB —  Thank you so much, Walter. I've been anxious to get back for some time. I'll certainly have a lot to say in London.
>
> WB  —  Oh, um...
>
> EAB —  Mediterranean leishmaniasis.
>
> WB  —  I beg your pardon?
>
> **EAB — It's a parasite. It will finally kill its host and therefore dies as well. I suggest you look it up.**

#### Why on Earth does Ashmead-Bartlett mention a parasite? I can't grasp how it relates to the rest of their conversation! English NOT my first language.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?  The meaning is obvious to me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Chenmunka Judging from the title, OP doesn't understand why parasites are being brought up in this context.

Comment: I've edited the question to try and clarify what you're asking; if I've misunderstood, feel free to [edit] the question further.

Comment: @F1Krazy thanks! **English ISN'T my first language!** You understood me perfectly!

Comment: I see.  My comnent was not about the language as such, but about the history of Gallipoli, which is very well known.